# What combination of string functions I should use to get this right in impala?

Tags: sql, impala

I want to separate this data

```
"trial: 1.28  :sprout: 1.28  :blossom: 1.088  :garden: 0.896  :standard: 1.088  :advance: 1.088"
```

in columns like column a 'trial' column b '1.28', column c 'sprout' column d '1.28' and so on.... 
can somebody help me with this?

Comment: Is the data provided in a single column of the table with string or char or varchar datatype or is it the data in the file? (Will creating a table with delimiter as : and this data solve your need?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function for this purpose. Main issue is you need to know how many possible split can be.

First remove all unwanted characters like : or double space. Then use below function to separate.

select split_part('trial: 1.28  :sprout: 1.28  :blossom:',' ',1)